# Is it possible to use hawkbit in multi tenant mode?

Tags: eclipse-hawkbit, hawkbit

How to start hawkbit in a multi tenant config?

If I set the tenant parameter (tenant-id or tenant_id) in authentication token via Keycloak (oidc), the DEFAULT tenant is always displayed in the UI.
Is a multi tenant config possible and what are the config parameters?

I can see the following log entry in hawkbit backend:
2023-08-03 12:59:19.014 DEBUG 1 --- [executor-pool-0] o.e.h.r.j.autoassign.AutoAssignChecker : Auto assign check call for tenant <MY_TENANT_XY> finished

Answer (score 0):

I believe the code for this is not open source. Bosch IOT offering has HawkBit running with multiple tenants but there's no way to set one up yourself without filling in the blanks (by writing the code to do it).